# How to get batch ID?

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I'm running some really long batch process. So in case user navigates away from the batch progress page, I'd like to be able to give him a link that leads back to that page. How can I get the batch ID needed for the batch processing page?

Knowing that batch processing url is something like `http://example.com/batch?op=start&id=183` so in theory I could look for the `$_GET['id']` inside my batch process function and store that in a session variable but it seems really ugly. Yet I didn't find any way to get the id of the batch that I just started.

It would be really nice if `batch_set()` would return batch id or would just add it to the batch definition array.

Answer (score 3):

After batch_set(). Use

```
$batch =& batch_get();
```

This contains the information you need.

But I'm not sure you will be able to resume.

Comment: It's no problem to resume when I navigate to `/batch?op=start&id=ID` but unfortunately in my case `batch_get()` returns array without batch ID. If you look at [batch_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/batch_set/7) you'll see that batch id is not being set inside that function. The batch ID is set inside [batch_process](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/batch_process/7) which is called later and NOT explicitly by my code.